# Angular4 + webpack + UI-Router and lazyloading (no systemjs)

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-ui-router

I am following the ngModules tutorial (https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule) 
combined with the quickstart example of UI-Router (https://github.com/ui-router/quickstart-ng2).

My setup for Angular 4 is webpack only.

I am trying to get lazyloading working without using SystemJS. Not sure if it is possible.

I also use Pug templates, which I import like:

```
import template from './contact.component.pug';

@Component( {
  selector: 'app-contact',
  template: template(),
} )
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types/"
  ],
  "outDir": "./dist/",
  "baseUrl": "./src/app/typings",
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "lib": [
    "es2015",
    "dom"
  ]
},
"include": [
  "src/**/*"
],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "**/*.spec.ts"
]}
```

I tried using SystemJS like in the UI-Router quickstart example, but that breaks the loading of my pug templates (the imports will not work, result is undefined).

So it looks like I am in between 2 worlds.

The only issue I have is that I cannot load the `crisis.module` in a lazy fashion.

```
export let MAIN_STATES: Ng2StateDeclaration[] = [
// The top-level app state.
// This state fills the root <ui-view></ui-view> (defined in index.html) with the AppComponent
{ name: 'app', component: AppComponent },
{ name: 'app.crisis.**', url: '/crisis', lazyLoad: loadNgModule( 'src/app/common/crisis/crisis.module' ) },
];
```

Does anyone have an tip?

Comment: Are you using webpack?  There is a webpack sample app at https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angular that has lazy loading in it

Comment: awesome. I will have a look. The Angular CLI makes live much easier, doesn't it